# Arithmetic encoding implementation outputting chars

Tags: encoding, compression, entropy

I am looking at the arithmetic coding implementation on https://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/adaptive-arithmetic-coding

My understanding is that when you're using floating point precision, the compressed result will be some floating point value. However, when using infinite precision with integers and shifting, I thought the output are binary values. In the above link, there's a function

```
def remove_first_digit(v):     # returns truncated value and digit which was truncated
    d = v // tail
    v %= tail
    return v, d
```

and `d` is appended to `output` which is the compressed result. However `d` here is a `char`. I don't quite understanding how this implementation works. Why is there a conversion to char going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Here `d` is not a "char". It is a base 27 digit, i.e. an integer in the range 0..26. `code_to_char()` then converts the digit into an upper-case letter or a period to write out.

This is not an arithmetic encoder that produces binary output. It is an arithmetic encoder that produces output consisting of those 27 characters.

What is going on there is that the high digit of the `low` and `high` values are equal, so that digit is written out, and then removed from both the `low` and the `high` values. Then new digits are shifted in to `low` and `high` -- a 0 digit into `low` and a 26 digit into `high`.